# AgileToolkit - Performance of save() in Model_Table with references

Tags: performance, model, save, agiletoolkit

I'm using AgileToolkit 4.2.4 and experiencing some performance problems when using Model_Table for inserting a large amount of items into a MySQL 5.5.31 database with InnoDB engine. After some testing I found out that the model becomes slow when using references, for instance with hasOne().

Performance tests:

```
<?php
$t = $this->add('Model_Test');

for ($i = 0; $i < 500; $i++)
{
    $t->unload();

    $t->set('field1', 1);
    $t->set('field2', 1);

    $t->save();
}
?>
```

Using model 1 (2.7 sec for 500 inserts):

```
<?php
class Model_Test extends Model_Table
{
    public $table = 'test';

    function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->addField('field1')->length(45);
        $this->addField('field2')->length(45);
    }
}
?>
```

Using model 2 (21.3 sec for 500 inserts):

```
<?php
class Model_Test extends Model_Table
{
    public $table = 'test';

    function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->hasOne('Test', 'field1');
        $this->hasOne('Test', 'field2');
    }
}
?>
```

For this example in model 2 I refer to instances of the same model Test, but it also occurs when I refer to some other model.

Is there anything I can do to overcome this problem? Furthermore, is this the right way to insert items using a model; adding it only once and do an unload() inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$t = $this->add('Model_Test');

for ($i = 0; $i < 500; $i++) {
    $t->set('field1', 1);
    $t->set('field2', 1);
    $t->saveAndUnload();     //  <--------
}
```

Method **save()** saves data and load them from database again to populate your model (this is how id autoincrement field appears in model). On other hand **saveAndUnload()** do not select any data from database after saving. If you add **->debug()** to your model you will see two requests when you use **save()** - insert and select.